# How to Prove the Apollonius Circle?

Tags: circles, plane-geometry, locus

Suppose we are given two points, say $A$ and $B$. Point $P$ is moving such that $$\frac{PA}{PB} = r \ne1,$$
where $r$ is constant. It is a well known result that the locus of $P$ is circle. This is one of the special cases of Circles of Apollonius.

I have a question in its proof. Please refer [Proof Using Angle Bisector Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circles_of_Apollonius#Proof_using_the_angle_bisector_theorem).

It is clear that every point on the locus lies on the circle with diameter $CD$ but the **converse** is not clear -- I couldn't show that every point on the circle with diameter $CD$ lies on the locus of $P$. I suppose similar triangles are useful here but I don't know how.

Please help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4733927