# How to prove the converse theorem of Circles of Apollonius.

Tags: geometry

[image]

We know that CFB angle is 90 degree, and we also know that $\frac{AC}{CD}$ = $\frac{AB}{DB}$, how to prove that FC is the bisector ?
 I can prove the two other forms of this question:
1- FC is the  bisector and $\frac{AC}{CD}$ = $\frac{AB}{DB}$. Prove CFB is a right triangle.

2-FC is the bisector and CFB is a right triangle. Prove $\frac{AC}{CD}$ = $\frac{AB}{DB}$.
But I can't prove this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### The identity method

We can use the identity method to take advantage of what you have proved.

Let $FC$ be the bisector of $\angle A'FD$, where $A'$ be a point on line $BC$ to the left of $C$.

Thanks to case 2 that you have proved, since $FC$ is the bisector of $\angle A'FD$ and $CFB$ is a right triangle, we must have $$\frac{A'C}{CD} = \frac{A'B}{DB}.$$
Together with the condition $\frac{AC}{CD}$ = $\frac{AB}{DB}$, we know
$$\frac{A'B}{A'C} = \frac{AB}{AC}$$
Substracting $1$ from both sides, we get
$$\frac{BC}{A'C} = \frac{BC}{AC},$$
which means $A'C=AC$. So $A'$ and $A$ are the same point. $FC$ is the bisector of $\angle AFD$, too.

##### Using vectors in Euclidean spaces

Let $\frac{AC}{CD}=\frac{AB}{BD}=\frac{d_1}{d_2}$. Then ${\overrightarrow {FC}}={\frac {d_{2}{\overrightarrow {FA }}+d_{1}{\overrightarrow {FB }}}{d_{2}+d_{1}}},\ {\overrightarrow {FD} }={\frac {d_{2}{\overrightarrow {FA }}-d_{1}{\overrightarrow {FB}}}{d_{2}-d_{1}}}.$

$ {\begin{aligned}
&FC\text{ is the bisector of } \angle AFD.\\
\iff &{FA} :{FB} =d_1:d_2.\\
\iff &d_2|{\overrightarrow {{FA} }}|=d_1|{\overrightarrow {{FB} }}|.\\
\iff &d_2^2|{\overrightarrow {{FA} }}|^2=d_1^2|{\overrightarrow {{FB} }}|^2.\\
\iff &(d_2{\overrightarrow {{FA} }}+d_1{\overrightarrow {{FB} }})\cdot (d_2{\overrightarrow {{FA} }}-d_1{\overrightarrow {{FB} }})=0.\\
\iff &{\overrightarrow {{FC} }}\cdot {\overrightarrow {{FD} }}=0.\\
\iff & \angle {{CFD} }=90^{\circ }.
\end{aligned}}$

This method is copy-pasted from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circles_of_Apollonius#Proof_using_vectors_in_Euclidean_spaces).

If you have not learned vectors, you can use analytic geometry. You would obtain a proof that is basically a translation of this proof into coordinates.